# UR5 Jogging using Jacobian

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-control, ur-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question, but here it is :

Based on the suggestions I found in the forums I am trying to get UR5 to jog.
I have set the type of

```
arm_controller :
    type: velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
```

So I am guessing, it needs only velocity commands.
Here is the code till now :

```
const std::vector<std::string> joint_names = jmg->getActiveJointModelNames();
ros::Rate loop_rate(5);
while(ros::ok()) {
              Eigen::MatrixXd jacobian = group->getCurrentState()->getJacobian(jmg);
    std::cout << "jacobian : " << jacobian << std::endl;

    Eigen::VectorXd ee_vel(6);
    ee_vel << -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    std::cout << "ee vel : " << ee_vel << std::endl;

    Eigen::VectorXd joint_vel = jacobian.inverse() * ee_vel;
    std::cout << "joint vel : " << joint_vel << std::endl;

    control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal goal;
             goal.trajectory.joint_names = joint_names;

    goal.trajectory.points.resize(1);
    goal.trajectory.points[0].positions.resize(6);
    std::vector<double> joint_vals = group->getCurrentJointValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        goal.trajectory.points[0].positions[i] = joint_vals[i];
    }

    goal.trajectory.points[0].velocities.resize(6);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
        goal.trajectory.points[0].velocities[j] = joint_vel[j];
    }
    // To be reached 1 second after starting along the trajectory
    goal.trajectory.points[0].time_from_start = ros::Duration(0.0);
    goal.trajectory.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    traj_client->sendGoal(goal);

    loop_rate.sleep();
}
```

I get a message saying :

```
[ INFO] [1475846670.761351237]: Received new trajectory execution service request...
[ INFO] [1475846670.761755780]: on_goal
[ INFO] [1475846670.981847762]: Execution completed: SUCCEEDED
[ INFO] [1475846672.982605141]: on_goal
```

But then the ur_driver crashes during the  first loop.

Even though UR5 driver is capable of streaming joint data,
In ur_driver.cpp

```
URDriver::setSpeed(...)
```

since there's no controller to support that, I am sending a joint trajectory with only one point in it.

The first few messages on ´/follow_joint_trajectory/goal´ are :

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1476096642
    nsecs: 351799456
  frame_id: ''
goal_id: 
  stamp: 
    secs: 1476096642
    nsecs: 351800506
  id:  
goal: 
  trajectory: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1476096642
        nsecs: 351783927
      frame_id: ''
    joint_names: ['shoulder_pan_joint', 'shoulder_lift_joint', 'elbow_joint', 'wrist_1_joint', 'wrist_2_joint', 'wrist_3_joint']
    points: 
      - 
        positions: [-0.33116084734071904, -1.6651738325702112, -1.6492660681353968, 3.313994884490967, -1.9009583632098597, 1.5703166723251343]
        velocities: [-0.7625009696124342, 2.0051739782259315, -2.213010444549463, 0.20772017660027928, -0.7625008941085881, -0.00035870155518285494]
        accelerations: []
        effort: []
        time_from_start: 
          secs: 0
          nsecs:         0
  path_tolerance: []
  goal_tolerance: []
  goal_time_tolerance: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
---
header: 
  seq: 1
  stamp: 
    secs: 1476096642
    nsecs: 551965302
  frame_id: ''
goal_id: 
  stamp: 
    secs: 1476096642
    nsecs: 551965571
  id: /cont_replan-3-1476096642.551965571
goal: 
  trajectory: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1476096642
        nsecs: 551939357
      frame_id: ''
    joint_names: ['shoulder_pan_joint', 'shoulder_lift_joint', 'elbow_joint', 'wrist_1_joint', 'wrist_2_joint', 'wrist_3_joint']
    points: 
      - 
        positions: [-0.3311851660357874, -1.6651976744281214, -1.6492541472064417, 3.314030647277832, -1.9010065237628382, 1.5701848268508911]
        velocities: [-0.7625342648492489, 2.0051424575369525, -2.2130284353503162, 0.2077758962011466, -0.7625341972159444, -0.0003395046112384696]
        accelerations: []
        effort: []
        time_from_start: 
          secs: 0
          nsecs:         0
  path_tolerance: []
  goal_tolerance: []
  goal_time_tolerance: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
---
```

Is my approach correct or is there a better way to do it? And why does the driver crash?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245390/ur5-jogging-using-jacobian/) by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2016-10-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2016-10-10**:
Is it possible that since the velocities are not starting from 0's, the driver is not able to handle these velocities? In that case, how to generate a `trapezoidal` profile for jog mode?

**Comment by [power93](https://answers.ros.org/users/34003/power93/) on 2018-03-05**:
Hi,
Is true that i can send sample by sample my trajectory using speedj? Is there an example in c++ of a path following sending sample each 125 Hz?
Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [Dreamer](https://answers.ros.org/users/123417/dreamer/) on 2022-11-11**:
Hi,I'm researching on admittance control of UR5, but I am confused about how to realize the velocity control of UR5? Your code shown in this page is of great helpful for me, but can you show more details about the header file which should be included?and what is the variable jmg?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: a new package that handles Jacobian jogging: [jog_arm](http://wiki.ros.org/jog_arm)

You can use UR's python interface, like this (bypassing ros_control). The downside is, there won't be any collision checking. We used a 50Hz loop rate.

```
        // Compose a string that contains URScript velocity command
      sprintf(cmd_, "speedl([%1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f], 0.2, 0.1)\n", delta.getX(), delta.getY(), delta.getZ(), 0., 0., 0.);
      ROS_INFO_STREAM(cmd_);
      
      // Copy command string to ROS message string
      urscriptString_.data = cmd_;
      
      // Send the compliant motion command to the UR5
      velPub_.publish(urscriptString_);
```

Our lab has also used the Jacobian method like you were trying to do, but only on a Motoman arm (never tried it with a UR).

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2016-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2016-10-10**:
Here's the publisher definition:

// Publisher for the velocity commands

velPub_ = n_.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/right_ur5_controller/right_ur5_URScript", 1);

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2016-10-10**:
the UR modern driver does exactly this. In `ur_realtime_communication.cpp`, the `setSpeed` function calls
``sprintf(cmd, "speedj([%1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f, %1.5f], %f)\n",q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, acc);`

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2016-10-10**:
Does the trajectory has to have at least 2 points? Which actually makes sense..

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2016-10-10**:
We're just sending one velocity command at a time, which works fine. But if you are sending position commands, I'm not sure.

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2016-10-11**:
No, as I mentioned, I am sending velocity commands

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2016-10-12**:
The solution works for me right now. Thanks!

**Comment by [toluwajosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33419/toluwajosh/) on 2018-01-25**:
Hi, could you please recommend a resource or provide a link to how I can obtain the Jacobian for a Motoman robot arm. I have tried some other methods and they don't seem to work.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2018-01-25**:
@intelharsh 's approach should work:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd jacobian = group->getCurrentState()->getJacobian(jmg);
```

Is MoveIt! set up correctly? Like, can you plan a move in RViz?

There's also a new pkg for this: [jog_arm](http://wiki.ros.org/jog_arm)

**Comment by [toluwajosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33419/toluwajosh/) on 2018-01-25**:
So, I'm trying to include this function in a node which works well with Rviz. After adding the code snippet and trying to make with catkin_make I get the error; 'undefined reference to robot_model_loader, etc. So I'm wondering what could I be doing wrong.

**Comment by [toluwajosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33419/toluwajosh/) on 2018-01-25**:
I'll check out the [jog_arm](http://wiki.ros.org/jog_arm). Thanks